# DIsplay Canvas image in WPF Datagrid Column using converter

Tags: wpf, image, canvas, datagrid, converters

I am total beginner trying to learn WPF/C#, Basically I want following:

- Show canvases in multiple places (usualy datagrid columns based on value)
- To use Convertor that will fetch right canvas (based on value and parameter) and return it as imagesource*
- I don't want to convert canvas to imagefile and return filepath

Understand that this is how i imagined to make it, if you have a better solution that doesn't include having image files in folder and using paths it will help me

I have the following XAML: (File: MyApp.Views.MainView.xaml)

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:ValueToImageConvertor x:Key="_ValueToImageConvertor" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding SomeValue,Converter={StaticResource _ValueToImageConvertor} ConverterParameter=SomeParameter}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is the Resource Dictionary where i store my canvases: (File: MyApp.Resources.ImagesDictionary.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources">


    <Viewbox x:Key="i_img1" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
            <Path Data="XXXXXXX" Fill="Black" />
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox x:Key="i_img2" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
            <Path Data="YYYYY" Fill="Black" />
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And i want to make a converter:(File: MyApp.Converters.ValueToImageConverter.cs)

```
 public class ValueToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
             //Based on value and parameter get specific canvas and display it
             //get canvas and convert it as image source without creating file

        }
    }
```

As i mentioned above, maybe this is a totally bad approach. I am newbie who is trying to learn. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I might put the ViewBox and the Canvas and the Path in the DataTemplate, and have the converter return a PathGeometry: `<Path Data="{Binding SomeValue, Converter={StaticResource Blah}...`

Comment: Nice idea, but what if i have multiple paths in canvas?

Comment: You didn't mention that. That wouldn't work then. If you want arbitrary content, you want a DataTemplateSelector. A DataTemplate can instantiate any visual content at all. For your scheme btw you need to put `x:Shared="False"` on the resources, or you'll only be able to use each one in one place at a given time. Also, you obviously can't stuff arbitrary visual elements into an image. You'd want `<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeValue,Converter={StaticResource _ValueToImageConvertor}...`

Answer (score 1):

Ok folks, i did it. This is how:

1) I have resource dictionary file ("Resources/ImagesDictionary.xaml")

```
<Viewbox x:Key="i_male" x:Shared="False">
    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path  Data="XXXXXX" Fill="Black" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>

<Viewbox x:Key="i_female" x:Shared="False">
    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Data="YYYYY" Fill="Black" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

2) My main xaml datagrid column for image in file ("Views/wndUsers.xaml")

```
    <Window.Resources>
      <conv:ValueToImageConverter x:Key="_ValueToImageConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sex" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
         <DataTemplate >
              <ContentControl Content="{Binding Sex, Converter={StaticResource 
_ValueToImageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

3) Converter ValueToImageConverter file ("Converters/ValueToImageConverter")

```
public class ValueToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private ResourceDictionary _resDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _resDictionary.Source = new Uri("Resources/ImagesDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "0":
                return (bool)value == true ? _resDictionary["i_female"] : _resDictionary["i_male"];

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this converter anywhere where u need an image based on value and parameter